# can i omit -m switch in iptables command?

Tags: networking, iptables

I want to block SSH access for a specified IP `xx.yy.zz.ww`. `-p` switch can  match all TCP traffic,so i feel it is no need to use `-m` to match tcp protocol again.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -s xx.yy.zz.ww -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 22 -s xx.yy.zz.ww -j DROP
```

Do the two above iptables commands take the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man iptables` says:

> iptables can use extended packet matching modules. These are loaded in two ways: implicitly, when **-p** or **--protocol** is specified, or with the **-m** or **--match** options, followed by the matching module name; after these, various extra command line options become available, depending on the specific module.

As such, `-p tcp` does indeed imply `-m tcp`. Additionally

- `-p icmp` implies `-m icmp`
- `-p udp` implies `-m udp`

No other matching modules are loaded automatically.